# Reference on how convolutions and multipliers relate in the sense of distributions

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis

The following is mentioned on Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)#Multiplier_operators_on_common_groups

"In the sense of distributions, there is no difference between multiplier operators and convolution operators; every multiplier T can also be expressed in the form $Tf = f*K$ for some distribution $K$, known as the convolution kernel of T. In this view, translation by an amount $x_0$ is convolution with a Dirac delta function $δ(· − x_0)$, differentiation is convolution with $δ'.$ "

Does anyone know of a text where this is outlined?

Comment: This book may be helpful: Introduction to the Theory of Distributions, F. G. Friedlander.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith you know on which page?

Comment: No.  I have to admit I read this book many, many years ago.  It was a nice introduction to distributions.  Maybe I was assuming that this would help.

Comment: OK, ill look around in the chapter of the kernal theorem, then. It is nice to have a good basic reference anyway!

Comment: It definitely would make one think of the answer that @Chris provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This amounts to the duality between convolution and multiplication under the Fourier transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). It states that
$$
\widehat{f *g} = \hat{f}\cdot\hat{g}.
$$
(This holds for the inverse Fourier transform also; $\mathcal{F}^{-1} f (x)$ is just $\mathcal{F}f(-x)$.)
A Fourier multiplier $m(D)$ acts on a (Schwartz, say) function $f$ by
$$
(\widehat{m(D)f})(\xi) = m(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi).
$$
Inverting the Fourier transform and using the convolution theorem gives
$$
m(D)f(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[m\cdot\hat{f}](x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(m) * \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{f})(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(m) * f(x).
$$
So, a Fourier multiplier is just a convolution with the inverse Fourier transform of the multiplier $m$.

Comment: I was thinking about this the wrong way..misinterpreted what was on wikipedia..